# A function corresponding to $(0,0)$, $(1,1)$, $(1+\frac12,2)$, $(1+\frac12+\frac14,3)$, $(1+\frac12+\frac14+\frac18, 4)$, etc

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus, functions, geometric-series

Earlier today I decided I wanted to see if I could make a function that would correspond to the following:

$$\begin{array}{c|c}
x & y \\ \hline
0 & 0 \\
1 & 1 \\
1+\frac12 & 2 \\
1+\frac12+\frac14 & 3 \\
1+\frac12+\frac14+\frac18 & 4 \\ 
\end{array}$$
and on and on...

So, to make a long story short, I have ended up putting functions in functions to end up with the right numbers in the $n$-th terms. It seems to never end. Surely I'm missing something. I'd be thrilled if anyone can fill me in.

Comment: Consider the value of $1/(2-x)$.

Comment: Note that the value of $x$ at $y=4$ is $2-\frac 18$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want $x$ as a function of $y$ you can use $$x=2-2^{1-y}$$
If you want $y$ as a function of $x$ you can use
$$y=-\log_2(2-x)+1$$

Comment: Beautiful! That is so lovely, I must say! I can't wait to mess around with it! Thank you very much!

Comment: can you recommend any reading on this subject? Thanks once more!

Comment: The critical thing is to realize the sums are $2-$ the last term.  You can prove that from the sum of a geometric series, but it comes up all the time specifically for powers of $2$, like $1+2+4+8+\ldots 2^n=2^{n+1}-1$.  Once you have that, my $x$ equation falls out and the $y$ one is just solving for $y$.

Comment: Great explanation, totally understandable now. Sorry about the notional issues on my end.